# Pesticide Chrome Extension: Is it possible to display Class Names on Hover/Click

Tags: css, class, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-development-server

I've been using the Pesticide Chrome extension to visualize webpage layouts. Is there a way to enhance its functionality to display class names when hovering or clicking on elements..??
Looking for insights or possible solutions. Thanks!

Toggled the Pesticide extension to visualize webpage layout. Expected to see class names displayed when hovering or clicking on layout boxes, but it didn't show.
Seeking guidance on making it display class names interactively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Holding down CTRL when hovering an element](https://github.com/mrmrs/pesticide/pull/43) will show a banner at the bottom listing its id and its [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
[image: Show Banner]

However, if you are asking to show CSS declarations, such as `testClass::hover` or other selectors, it is not supported by this extension. Also, note that a class list is a collection of the `class` attributes of the element, which is entirely different from CSS declarations.